# i have a trouble about:No Activity found to handle Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

i want to start an intent in a service,the intent is used to called somebody.
follow is my code:

```
Intent call=new Intent("android.intent.action.CLL",Uri.parse("******");
call.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);  
startActivity(call);
Log.d("test","success");
```

and the AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".detimecall"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
<service android:name=".gettime" />
    </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

how can i solution this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your code is incorrect:

```
Intent call=new Intent(android.intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("******");
```

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_CALL) for more on intents.